# How to populate Dropdowlistfor in ASP.NET MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

VIEW

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SupplierId,
    new SelectList(new Pharmacy_Project.Models.Supplier().SupplierList, "Value", "Text"), 
    new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Controller

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierList
{
    get
    {
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var list = (from s in db.Suppliers select s).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                 Text = x.SupplierName,
                 Value = x.SupplierId.ToString()
            });
            return list;
        } 
    }
}
```

Error:

> The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.

I tried to change `return list.Tolist();` but I then encounter this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store
>   expression.

Comment: `var list = (from s in db.Suppliers select s).ToList().Select(..` But why on earth are you creating another `SelectList` from the original one in the view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i just tried that i saw that on another article.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is the original code. var list = (from s in db.Suppliers
                        select new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = s.SupplierName,
                            Value = s.SupplierId.ToString()
                        }
                        );

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see you are in a bad mood today, :) checking out your   comments on other Questions.

Comment: Yes I know - use the code in my last comment.

Comment: And you can simplify all this using `ViewBag.SupplierList = new SeelctList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierId", "SupplierName");` and `@HtmlDropDownListFor(m => m.SupplierId, (SelectList)ViewBag.SupplierList)` or even better, use a view model with a property `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke how do i flag my question as solve. i already figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to materialize you query first using `.ToList()` (or `AsEnumerable()`)

```
var list = (from s in db.Suppliers select s).ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem{ ... }
```

Side note: You have already created `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` so ceating another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the view is pointless extra overhead and you view should be just

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SupplierId, Pharmacy_Project.Models.Supplier().SupplierList, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

or better still, use a view model with a property `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SupplierList { get; set; }` and populate it in the controller before you send it to the view, so that the view is

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SupplierId, Model.SupplierList, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

Note also that you can also use `new SelectList(db.Suppliers, "SupplierId", "SupplierName")` to generate the `SelectList`